# node.js table search fails with promises in use

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, bluebird, es6-promise

I'm going to learn something here. I love to learn! Thanks in advance for any help!

Here's 30 lines of Node.js JavaScript. It's a standard table search. For simplicity, my "table" is a sequence of 16 integers, 0 to 15. Function compareRow reports whether a guessed row *r* has a row number below, equal, or above a row corresponding to a transaction *t*; *t* needs row number *r = t*. (Sure, the longer code is more complex.) I've removed everything I could to de-clutter for you.

Asynchronous issues (and some of you here in past questions) have encouraged me to use Promises. My longer code requires *bluebird* and gets identical results. This code uses JavaScript Promises.

```
'use strict'
function compareRow(r, t, low, high) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    console.log('compareRow   r=' + r + '   t=' + t + '   low=' + low +
        '   high=', high)
    return resolve(r - t)
  })
}
function findRow(t) {
  let lo = 0, hi = 15, mid
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    let mustBreak = false
    let count = 0, maxCount = 3
    do {
      mid = Math.floor((lo + hi) / 2)
      compareRow(mid, t, lo, hi)
      .then(function(ans, error) {
        console.log('findRow got compareRow(' + mid + ')=' + ans)
        if (error) { mustBreak = true; return reject(error) }
        else if (ans === 0) { mustBreak = true; return resolve(mid) }
        else if (ans < 0) lo = mid
        else if (ans > 0) hi = mid
      })
    } while (!mustBreak && ++count < maxCount)
  })
}
findRow(2)
.then(function(ans1, err1) {
  console.log('for findRow(2):   ans=' + ans1 + '   err=' + err1)
})
```

Self-critique:

- The use of variable *mustBreak* is icky. At each place I've used *mustBreak=true*, I'd rather both *break* and *return resolve(n)* (or whatever).
- I recognize that within the callback functions, JavaScript treats my promise returns (*return resolve(1)*, for example) as returns from the callback functions, not from the promise functions at the top of the function. Hence, at each such call, JavaScript tracks two chains of execution: one for the *resolve* or *reject* and one for code listed after the callback. Ick. That second one is an unintended chain of execution.
- JSHint doesn't like the callback function involving *ans*. It correctly recognizes the function to be inside the *for* loop. Ick, except that this good advice in JSHint may not best account for callback functions.

Based on console.log messages I have since removed, execution runs as I wanted through line 17 (*compareRow(mid, t, lo, hi)*). I expected console.log would show me something like:

```
compareRow   r=7   t=2   low=0   high= 15
findRow got compareRow(7)=5
compareRow   r=3   t=2   low=0   high= 7
findRow got compareRow(3)=1
compareRow   r=1   t=2   low=0   high= 3
findRow got compareRow(1)=-1
compareRow   r=1   t=2   low=1   high= 3
findRow got compareRow(3)=1
compareRow   r=2   t=2   low=1   high= 3
findRow got compareRow(3)=0
for findRow(2):   ans=2   err=undefined
```

Instead, I got:

```
compareRow   r=7   t=2   low=0   high= 15
compareRow   r=7   t=2   low=0   high= 15
compareRow   r=7   t=2   low=0   high= 15
findRow got compareRow(7)=5
findRow got compareRow(7)=5
findRow got compareRow(7)=5
```

It appears

- Execution gets into *compareRow* (possibly in a timely way), but doesn't get on time into the callback function that receives that answer, resulting in an infinite loop.
- Or at least, that loop would be infinite except for the loop counter that limits the loop to three cycles.
- Given that the loop stops, it appears no accident that callback processes the answers (*findRow got compareRow(7)=5*) and gets called the same number of times the loop ran (three times).
- By the time that callback code runs, the code to process the output is no longer listening.

Questions:

- Is there a way I can encourage the JavaScript scheduler to process the code as I intend? (This seems an entirely standard use case for Promises!)
- How can I write this code better?

EDIT: Wording and question changes; all to the same effect as the original post. Deleted many lines of code. Corrected a syntax error.

Comment: So your actual `compareRow` function is genuinely asynchronous? Currently your code looks like it would better have been written without promises :-)

Comment: That `do while` loops won't wait for the promises you create inside its body. You cannot use such loops with asynchronous code. Use a recursive approach instead, wherein you can call the next step from an asynchronous promise callback.

Answer (score 0):

@Bergi: Well done indeed! If you care about points in Stack Overflow, please post some wording in an answer and I'll make yours the accepted solution.

I said at the start I'd learn something here. I did, indeed. The following is an anti-pattern because JavaScript doesn't interrupt the loops "for the promises you create inside its body. You cannot use such loops in asynchronous code."

```
NOTE: Don't do this at home!
do {
  callPromiseFunction()
  .then(function(results, error) {
    // do something with results
  })
} while (/*some condition*/)
```

The alternative: "Use a recursive approach instead, wherein you can call the next step from an asynchronous promise callback."

I also learned that the following works. I don't know that it's to be emulated, but it proved sufficient on this code.

```
NOTE: This was sufficient in this code to start the promise chain.
return new Promise
.all([callNonrecursivePromiseFunc(1), callNonrecursivePromiseFunc(2)]
.then(function(result, error) {
  callRecursivePromiseFunction(result)
  .then(function(results, error) {
    // do something with results
  })
})
```

Here's how I used Bergi's advice to change my code. It works. Finally. Whew! Again, I've removed lots of error checking and such to reduce the bulk.

```
'use strict'
let Promise = require('bluebird')
function compareRow(t, r, low, high) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    console.log('compareRow   t=' + t + '   r=' + r + '   low=' + low +
        '   high=', high)
    let recursion = (r === null)  // distraction; skip it
    if (recursion) {
      r = Math.floor((low + high) / 2)
      if (r < t) low = r
      else if (r > t) high = r
      else if (r === t) return resolve(r)
      compareRow(t, null, low, high)  // recursion; this is the point
      .then(function(result, error) {
        return resolve(result)
      })
    } else {
      return resolve(r - t)  // distraction; skip it
    }
  })
}
function findRow(t) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    let lo = 0, hi = 15
    console.log('findRow   t=' + t + '   lo=' + lo + '   hi=' + hi)
    return new Promise
    .all([compareRow(t, lo, lo, hi), compareRow(t, hi, lo, hi)])
    .then(function(result, error) {
      let ans = result[0]
      console.log('findRow got compareRow(' + lo + ')=' + ans)
      if (ans === 0) return resolve(lo)
      ans = result[1]
      console.log('findRow got compareRow(' + hi + ')=' + ans)
      if (ans === 0) return resolve(hi)
      compareRow(t, null, lo, hi)  // this is a recursive call
      .then(function(result, error) {
        return resolve(result)
      })
    })
  })
}
findRow(2)
.then(function(ans1, err1) {
  console.log('for findRow(2):   ans=' + ans1 + '   err=' + err1)
})
```

Comment:

- Please note the use of bluebird Promises. This code fails with JavaScript Promises.
- With the recursive approach:

  - The need for variable *mustBreak* went away. That was an "Ick".
  - Each time I call "resolve" or "reject", I'm in the same scope as the declarations. That was an "Ick".
  - At no point do I define a function within a loop. JSHint is happier. That was an "Ick".
- This code has some unwelcome complexity in that I use compareRow for both a recursive and a non-recursive purpose. Ick. I'm falling short of elegance here.

Comment: Now avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572) and you'll get an upvote from me :-) Hint: just `return compareRow(t, null, lo, hi);`